Robust regression with S estimator
I am trying to run robust regression with M estimator and S estimator using "lmrob". The default method is "MM" which is equivalent to "SM". But I also want to use "S" estimator and "M" estimator. Can I specify method="M" and method="S"?
I am not sure if the package "lmrob" supports S estimator and M estimator.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
